# Integrity error in Django

Tags: python, django-models, django-rest-framework

While I use POST to create new fields in database getting an error as follows,

```
IntegrityError at /api/signup/wallet/
SignUp_wallet_table.bank_ac_num_id may not be NULL
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value:    
SignUp_wallet_table.bank_ac_num_id may not be NULL
```

I also  submitting my **models.py** file here

**#models.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
class bank_table(models.Model):
    bank_ac_num=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    bank_ifci_code=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user_status=models.IntegerField(max_length=1,default=1)
class wallet_table(models.Model):
    mob_num=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,max_length=10,unique=True)
    bank_ac_num=models.ForeignKey(bank_table,null=True)    
    wallet_amnt=models.IntegerField(default=0)
class user_table(models.Model):
    user_id=models.IntegerField(primary_key=True,unique=True)
    user_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mob_num=models.ForeignKey(wallet_table,null=True)
```

Whole project file available  [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0DlE-Qi4Fu6b0RDM2ZvOVFVQlU)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that you added `null=True` after running `manage.py migrate`. You'll need to modify your database schema to allow null values in that column. Try to run again this:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: @JPG, can you try setting `bank_ac_num=models.ForeignKey(bank_table, blank=True, null=True)`. Then run migrations again.